# Issue with force.com site VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, force.com, site.com

Need help for a force.com site requirement.

A visualforce page is hosted on force.com site.
Using StandardController with extensions in VF page for a custom object.
Whenever a new custom object record is created, it creates as URL link (formula field -> https://dev.sandbox.my.salesforce-sites.com/form?id=a0O3L000002iSXO).

Objective is to send this above url as link to external user and insert information in SF on SUBMIT.

Apex class

```
public with sharing class formController {
public customObj1__c obj1 { get; set; }
public customObj1__c obj1Existing;
public String selectedContact { get; set; }
public string r1 { get; set; }
public string r2 { get; set; }    
public string r3 { get; set; }
public customObj2__c Clist{ get; set; }
public String recordId;
public String Type { get; set; }
public String fileName { get; set; }
public transient  blob file { get; set; }
public String title{ get;set; }
public ContentVersion cv { get; set; }
String contactId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('Id');   



public PageReference upload() {
        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.versionData = file;
        cv.title = title;
        cv.pathOnClient = fileName;
        cv.FirstPublishLocationId = contactId; 
        try
        {
            Insert cv;
        }
        catch (DMLException e)
        {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading Document in Library'));
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            cv = new ContentVersion();
        }
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Document uploaded successfully to library'));
        return null;
    } 

public PageReference redirect() {
    PageReference currentPage = ApexPages.currentPage();
    currentPage.setRedirect(true);
} 

public formController() {
    recordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    system.debug('recordId >>>>' +recordId);
    if (String.isNotBlank(recordId)) {
        getData();
    } 
}

  private  void getData() {
    List<customObj1__c> records = [SELECT Id, Name,Field1__c, Field2__c, Field3__c, R1__c, R2__c, R3__c,Link__c FROM CustomObj1__c 
                                   WHERE Id = :recordId LIMIT 1 FROM customObj1__c WHERE Id = :recordId];
    
      system.debug(records.size());
      if (records.size() > 0) {
        obj1Existing = records[0];
        obj1 = obj1Existing.clone(false);
    }
} 

public PageReference submit() {       
    String recordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');  
    system.debug('recordId SUBMIT>>>>' +recordId);
    customObj1__c obj1 = [SELECT Id, Name,Field1__c, Field2__c, Field3__c, R1__c, R2__c, R3__c FROM CustomObj1__c 
                                                            WHERE Id = :recordId LIMIT 1 FROM customObj1__c WHERE Id = :recordId];
    
    responseList = new customObj2__c();     
    
    responseList.Name = records.Name;   
    responseList.customObj1__c = recordId;     
    responseList.R1__c = r1;
    responseList.R2__c = r2;
    responseList.R3__c = r3;
    
    obj1.Id = obj1Existing.Id;
    formController_WS.updateObject(obj1);
    obj1.Id = NULL; 
    obj1.Link__c= null;// updated     
     upload(); //updated
    
    System.debug('responseList.Name value before insert: ' + responseList.Name);
    System.debug('responseList.customObj1__c value before insert: ' + responseList.customObj1__c);
    System.debug('Before insert: ' + responseList);
    PageReference pageref = new PageReference('/apex/Thankyoupage');
    redirect(); //updated
    System.debug('After insert: ' + responseList);
    System.debug('After insert: ' + responseList.Id);
    return pageref;
}   

public List<SelectOption> getYesNoOptions() {
List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
options.add(new SelectOption('Yes', 'Yes'));
options.add(new SelectOption('No', 'No'));
return options;
 } 
}


  -----------------------------------------------------------------

  public without sharing class formController_WS {
public static void updateObject(sObject recordToUpdate) {
    update recordToUpdate;
    
 }
}
```

VF page

```
<apex:page controller="formController" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" lightningStylesheets="true" sidebar="false"> 
<html>
   <body>
        <apex:form >
            <apex:slds />
            <div class="slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-col">
                <apex:panelGrid columns="1" width="100%">
                                <apex:pageBlock mode="Account"> 
                                    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 1" columns="1" collapsible="true">
                                        <apex:selectRadio label="Question 1?" 
                                                          value="{!obj1.R1__c}"
                                                          rendered="{!obj1.Field1__c != 'Allowed'}"
                                                          required="true"
                                                          >
                                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!yesNoOptions}" />
                                        </apex:selectRadio>
                                       <apex:selectRadio label="Question 2 ?" 
                                                          value="{!obj1.R2__c}" required="true">
                                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!yesNoOptions}" />
                                        </apex:selectRadio>
                                        
                                        <apex:selectRadio label="Question 3?" 
                                                          value="{!obj1.R3__c}" required="true">
                                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!yesNoOptions}" />
                                        </apex:selectRadio>
                                            </apex:pageBlockSection>
  <div style="width:100%; text-align:left;" align="Left">
                                        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Documents" columns="2" >
                                            <!--<apex:messages /> -->
                                           <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                                                    <apex:outputLabel >Title</apex:outputLabel>
                                                <apex:inputText value="{!title}"/>
                                                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                                                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                                                    <apex:outputLabel >File Upload</apex:outputLabel>
                                                    <apex:inputFile value="{!file}" fileName="{!fileName}" /> 
                                                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 

                                            <div class="slds-m-top_medium" align="Center">
                                            <apex:commandbutton style="font-size: 18px; margin-bottom: 20px; background-color:#DAA520;color:white;" action="{!upload}" value="Upload" status="status" rendered="false" />
                                            <apex:commandbutton style="font-size: 18px; margin-bottom: 20px; background-color:#DAA520;color:white;" action="{!redirect}" value="redirect" status="status" rendered="false" />
                                           </div>
                                            </apex:pageBlockSection>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="slds-m-top_medium" align="Center">
                                        <apex:commandButton value="SUBMIT" action="{!submit}" immediate="true"/>
                                    </div>  
                                    </apex:pageBlock>
                    </apex:panelGrid>
                </div>
            </div>
        </apex:form> 
    </body>
</html>
 </apex:page>
```

This form is not placed in in SF as record page.
Controller is always printing NULL.  Please advise how to proceed.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the external user a Community User or the Guest Site User? Also, you'll need to update your code example to show what type of sharing you are using - that is alost certainly the issue here

Comment: public FormController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        recordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');   
    CustomObj__c  form =(CustomObj__c)controller.getRecord(); system.debug(recordId); //Printing null

Comment: Its guest site user and its with sharing. Also also doing conditional rendering in VF page, added sharing rules as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things to review. Guest Site User has it's [own set of sharing rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_sharing_rules_guest.htm&type=5) - so if you are using a standard controller, you would need to make sure the record is [shared](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_networks_guest_user_sharing_rule.htm&release=222&type=5) with the specific GSU you are using.

But - in recent years, SF has removed the ability for the GSU to update any records using standard functionality. So if you are looking for someone to receive that link, and update a record, you would need to refactor that code to use a custom controller, and run the DML update in a class that is running without sharing.

Edit - also note that if you try and render an existing record on a page, you will often encounter issues because the GSU can't have update access. One workaround is to store the Id of the record in a variable, clone the record you retrieve via SOQL and remove the Id, and then expose the cloned version on the page, since that doesn't have an Id. Finally, on save, set the Id on the cloned version, and run the update in a Without Sharing Class.

But at that point, I would also consider just exposing an Experience Cloud page via GSU, since you can then use Flow and\or LWC, which is easier to use in this context.

And in Spring 24, we'll get the option to [run Platform Events as the Default Workflow User](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_run_event_triggered_flows_as_workflow_user.htm&release=248&type=5), so you could then just insert a record in a staging table which GSU can do, and fire a Platform Event to process it via Default Workflow User.

There is lots of helpful information [here](https://www.learnexperiencecloud.com/article/Guest-User-Record-Access-Development-Best-Practices#CRUDFLSChecksInApex), and you can refer to the answer I gave [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/330534/enforcing-guest-user-object-permission-changes-how-can-guest-user-edit-custom-o) for some more context

As a simple POC, here's what you can do to enable GSU to update a record:

```
<apex:page id="DemoPage" showHeader="false" sideBar="false"  controller="DemoController">

    <apex:form id="formdemo">

        <apex:pageBlock id="pb">
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Existing Policy?"></apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!objNew1.Policy__c}">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="secondpanel"/>
                    </apex:inputField>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputPanel id="secondpanel">
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(objNew1.Policy__c == 'Yes', true, false)}">
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!objNew1.Policy_Number__c}"></apex:inputField>
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:outputPanel>


                <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!submit}"></apex:commandButton>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

//Class for Controller

```
    public with sharing class DemoController {

    public Integration_Staging_Data__c objNew1 {get;set;}
    public Integration_Staging_Data__c objExisting;
    public String recordId;

    public DemoController() {
        recordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        if (String.isNotBlank(recordId)) {
            getData();
        }
    }

    private  void getData() {
        List<Integration_Staging_Data__c> records = [Select Id, Policy__c, Policy_Number__c FROM Integration_Staging_Data__c WHERE Id = :recordId];
        if (records.size() > 0) {
            objExisting = records[0];
            objNew1 = objExisting.clone(false);
        }
    }

    public PageReference submit() {
        objNew1.Id = objExisting.Id;
        DemoController_WS.updateObject(objNew1);
        objNew1.Id = NULL;
        return null;
    }

}
```

Without Sharing class to do update

```
  public without sharing class DemoController_WS {

    public static void updateObject(sObject recordToUpdate) {
        update recordToUpdate;
    }

}
```

Finally, add Sharing Rule:
[image]

Comment: Thanks BritishBoyinDC for your guidance. If I use custom controller, conditional rendering is not working, which is part of requirement. This is where I'm struggling.

Comment: Yes, I did follow these steps mentioned in the help document for creating sharing rules for guest user. Until that I was getting authorization error, even though I gave all object and field level permissions.

Comment: If the conditional rendering is on the VF side, then it shouldn't matter if it is standard vs custom - you are just pointing at a record variable. But - the GSU will give you issues if you try and render an existing record because the GSU can't have access to the record. See update above

Comment: SF user has a set of 7 questions (picklist fields). Based on answers to these questions, Im doing conditional rendering of around another 39 fields. So, while creating record customObj__c, I'm capturing the site URL_recordId in a URL field. This link has to be sent to GSU. Then the responses to be captured in detail object of customObj__c.

Comment: Thank you, BritishBoyinDC, for all your time. I tried to follow above instructions but still DML is not working. Refactored code as per suggestions. Can you please provide some more help that I can follow.

Comment: Here is what I'm trying to achieve -
I have custom obj A, its has set of 7 questions. Based on these 7 questions, which will we entered by SF user, another set of 39 questions should render/hide, as per selection.
Then these rendered questions need to be sent to GSU as an email. 
once the GSU submits, the response should be captured in another custom object B(to store responses of form sent - custom object A and custom Object B are MD relationship. Requirement says, SF user can send N no of links so every time a response comes in from GSU, it should create a record of custom obj B)

Comment: getting this error - Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: a0O3L000002XXX: []

Comment: Any DML has to be performed in a class without sharing - specifically, inserting into the child object probably requires r\w access to the parent, which the GSU can never have. 
So make sure any DML is in a class like the DemoController_WS in the sample code

Comment: Thank you so much BritishBoyinDC. Yes, had an insert operation in controller, which was throwing error. Made changes as per you suggestion above. Both parent-child objects, gave R/W access. Now, not getting any error and redirecting to Thank You page, which I added in return pageRef. But child record is not getting created. Anything else I need to do here? As per debug log, child record is getting created but no record in SF, child record Id is null. Please advise.

Comment: I think you would need to add some more code to the question so I can see how you are  creating each object

Comment: Updated question. Thank you :-)

Comment: I don't see where responseList is created? And is there a reason you requery for customObj1__c in the submit method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151220/discussion-between-sf-developer-and-britishboyindc).

Comment: @BritishcBoyinBC - After save, the responses are getting saved and not getting cleared. Could you please share any suggestions for this? I already tried cache=false and other solutions suggested in other articles, nothing worked for me. Please help

Comment: Are you resetting the temporary variables? Or do a pagereference with redirect = true to reset the viewstate

Comment: I'm redirecting to thank you page.  PageReference pageref = new PageReference('/apex/Thankyoupage'); return pageref;

Comment: Did you set redirect = true though - that would cause a new page to be instantiated

Comment: No, I didn't. In site settings, Cache public Visualforce pages is checked. I unchecked and tested but not working

Comment: set redirect = true didnt work for my scenario. Even if I change response and save, it created new record but displaying old values

Comment: I think you would need to post a more complete set of code somewhere - what you are trying to do is definitely possible, so not sure where the issue is without being able to see it in more detail